# How To Ignore SQL Update Notification

Tags: sql-server, update

I have a very weird situation.

One of our SQL Servers has a software update notification pending for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (KB2528583). However, this server is already at SP2. Here is the result of the @@Version query:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4033.0 (X64).

If the SQL Server is already at SP2 why do I have an SP1 update notification?
Is there a way to ignore this update notification for just this one machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could also be that you applied the update to SQL Server but didn't apply it to other services (SSAS, SSRS, etc.) or to other components (like Management Tools). Run SP2 again (or upgrade to something even newer!) and see which components it finds eligible for an update - I bet there is at least one.

Answer (score 2):

By any chance are multiple instances of SQL Server running on this host machine?

Check the Services console to see if more than one service of SQL Server is running. If so, the newly discovered one may be running the older service pack.

Comment: It could also be that you applied the update to SQL Server but didn't apply it to other services (SSAS, SSRS, etc.) or to other components (like Management Tools). Run SP2 again (or [SP3](https://sqlblog.org/2014/09/28/sql-server-2008-r2-service-pack-3-is-available)!) and see which components it finds eligible for an update - I bet there is at least one.

Comment: No. There is only one instance of SQL Server running on this machine.

Comment: @CapeCodeGunny and does it have client tools, other services, etc.? Humor us and kick off the SP2 installer anyway, and see what components it says do need to be updated.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - +1 I downloaded SP3 as you suggested and it installed perfectly. The system is now updated and in synch. Thank you. Please make your comment an answer and I will accept it.